# Disable mod_rewrite for subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm running a CMS using mod_rewrite for pretty URLs, but I have another site running in a subdirectory under the CMS that requires URL rewriting disabled, so I added a couple lines in the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
Options +ExecCGI

AddHandler php5-cgi .php
Action php-cgi /cgi-bin/php-wrapper.cgi
Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php-wrapper.cgi

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Added following two lines
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir/
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works, HOWEVER one of the directories under `/dir/` is protected using `mod_auth` and is still being rewritten. If I take out the `Require valid-user` directive in the `.htaccess` file for this directory, everything works great.

Here is the `.htaccess` file from the protected directory:

```
RewriteEngine off

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Administration"
AuthUserFile "/home/user/admin/.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

Any help would be appreciated. This has been bugging me for weeks! I did some Googling and others have had this problem, but I haven't found a solution.

Comment: Just a note that when I say it "works" after removing Require valid-user, I mean the redirection works, but my directory is of course no longer protected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem, Michael, and finally found [the solution](http://www.myriadinteractive.com/blog/view/id/29/conflict-between-apache-url-rewriting-and-basic-authentication)

> For basic authentication, the server
>   writes a "401 Unauthorized" header and
>   then looks for an error document based
>   on a pre-defined path. Most of the
>   time, the error document won't exist
>   in the directory that you want to
>   protect, so the request gets handled
>   by the rewrite engine which throws a
>   404 error.
>
> The solution to this problem is pretty
>   straightforward. You need to add a
>   single line of code to your .htaccess
>   file instructing Apache to ignore the
>   error document. When you're done, the
>   code should look something like this:
>
> ```
> ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized Access"
>
> RewriteEngine off
>
> AuthType Basic
> AuthName "Administration"
> AuthUserFile "/home/user/admin/.htpasswd"
> require valid-user
> ```

Hope that works for you!

Comment: YES! Thanks so much. I ended up finding a workaround, but it was one of those problems that kept on bugging me. Anyway, this solution worked like a charm :)

Comment: This drove me crazy for a while.  `RewriteEngine off` by itself worked. The password lines by themselves worked. But combine the two and you get 404s.  Thanks!

Comment: Genius! Your advice saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Manni:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and ditch the two rules you added (assuming I've understood the problem correctly), and remove the RewriteEngine from the protected .htaccess.

Comment: This was what I initially tried. This does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to enclose the Rewrite statements into a <DirectoryMatch> statement next. You could simply use it with inverse logic to match every directory but the one that should not be rewritten:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/(?!dir)">
    RewriteEngine on
    ...
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have pointed out that this is on a shared hosting account, so I can't modify httpd.conf. DirectoryMatch is not allowed within .htaccess. I did try it anyway, and no luck.